# How to add nuget package to project (not solution) with build

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# solution which has two projects (P1 & P2). Both P1 & P2 have set of nuget packages. In TFS I created one folder (say Lib folder) where I put all actual .nuget files.

At the .sln folder level I created a .nuget folder & put the package.config. This has the list of packages which I am using in P1 & P2 projects. Following is the content of package.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Route" version="1.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Now when I build the solution it creates a "packages" folder under same directory where .sln file resides & then it unzips all the nuget packages. I want to add those nuget package to either P1 or P2. I do not want to do add packges manually to each project.Currently packages are unzipping only but not getting added to the project.

Can anyone tell me how to automatically add the required packages to the project during build.

Comment: Can you explain why you do not want to use NuGet as intended (i.e. using the Visual Studio UI or the NuGet command line to add packages to the projects as opposed to modifying the .config file yourself)?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks very suspicious ... Personally i would recommend to you to add your packages in a common way !!


But if you insist ... I have one a little ugly idea how to implement it.

Before build you have to change your `.csproj` files in order to include these packages into build. So you have to add sections like this `<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer"> <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath></Reference>` inside `<ItemGroup>` node in csproj file. 

You can write utility(simple enough) which accomplishes it for you and execute it before build(Solution-->Properties-->Build Events -->Pre build events)


Also(most probably) you will need some configuration file for this new utility(Utility has to know what packages need certain project). It will be for example text file with the following content

```
<ProjectName>
  <Package Id = 2>
  <Package Id = 24>
</ProjectName>
```

You will need to parse this config file and modify every `csproj` file with appropriate references.